# Multiline string search using sed or perl

Tags: perl, search, command-line, sed, multiline

You might say that this is a duplicate post ... but I have tried previous solutions and they do not seem to work! For perl for some reason I see solutions involving substitution replacement but they replace the text matching pattern instead of displaying it!. Below is the source text

```
ClassOne:error=9607
ClassTwo:This is junk test
ClassThree:I|want|to|extract|this|text|after|error=9607
```

I want to extract all lines containing `ClassThree:....` after I have found `error=9607`. Preferably I want a single line command to accomplish this because I will run it across multiple files on large number of servers (using command in line with ssh command).

Help/pointers in this regard is appreciated.

Comment: Thanks all for solutions! Unfortunately none of the below commands worked on my servers which I think would be because of old version of AIX which runs on my server. Luckily I looked more into `awk` based on @potong's comments and that seemed to have the solution `awk /begin/,/end/ filename ` pretty neat eh? :-)

Answer (score 1):

If `ClassThree` will always be 2 lines after the `error=9607`, you can just:

```
grep -A 2 'error=9607' input.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
sed '/error=9607/,/ClassThree/{//!d}' file
ClassOne:error=9607
ClassThree:I|want|to|extract|this|text|after|error=9607
```

If you only want the `ClassThree` line:

```
sed '/error=9607/,/ClassThree/{/ClassThree/!d}' file
ClassThree:I|want|to|extract|this|text|after|error=9607
```

If you want all lines containing `ClassThree` thereafter:

```
cat <<! >file
> ClassOne:error=9607
> ClassTwo:This is junk test
> ClassThree:I|want|to|extract|this|text|after|error=9607
> ClassOne:error=9608
> ClassTwo:This is junk test
> ClassThree:I|want|to|extract|this|text|after|error=9607
> ClassOne:error=9609
> ClassTwo:This is junk test
> ClassThree:I|want|to|extract|this|text|after|error=9607
>!
sed '/error=9607/h;G;/ClassThree.*\n./P;d' file
ClassThree:I|want|to|extract|this|text|after|error=9607
ClassThree:I|want|to|extract|this|text|after|error=9607
ClassThree:I|want|to|extract|this|text|after|error=9607
```

or this awk solution:

```
 awk '/error=9607/{p=1};/ClassThree/ && p' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a perl attempt

Edit: I added specific error checking as well

```
use strict;
my @errors = (9607,9608);
open(FILE,"filescan.txt")||die "Error: cannot read file\n$!";
while(<FILE>){
    chomp(my $line = $_ );
    if ( $line =~ /^ClassOne:error=(\d+)/ ) {
        my $errorCode = $1;
        if ( grep { $_ == $errorCode } @errors ) {
            print "$line\n";
            while(<FILE>){
                chomp(my $line = $_ );
                if ( $line =~ /^ClassThree:.*\|error=$errorCode/ ) {
                    print "$line\n";
                    last;
                }
            }
            print "----------\n";
        }
    }
}
close FILE;
```

Output:

```
ClassOne:error=9607
ClassThree:I|want|to|extract|this|text|after|error=9607
----------
ClassOne:error=9608
ClassThree:I|want|to|extract|this|text|after|error=9608
----------
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ perl -ple 'print if /^ClassThree/ && /error=9607/ .. /\0/' file
```